# Array handling using Awk

Tags: perl, shell, unix, sed, awk

I have two input files, one just containing numbers e.g.

**range.txt**

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
9  
10  
11    
12  
13  
14  
15  
16  
17  
18
```

The other file has the requirements. For e.g

**requirements.txt**

```
2s 4m  
1s 10m
```

What that means is 2 sets of 4 members each and 1 set of 10 member.

The output should look like :

```
There is 1 apple;  
There are 2 mangoes and 1 apple;   
There are 3 mangoes and 1 apple;   
There are 4 mangoes and 1 apple;  
There is 5 apple;  
There are 6 mangoes and 5 apple;  
There are 7 mangoes and 5 apple;  
There are 8 mangoes and 5 apple;  
There is 9 apple;  
There are 10 mangoes and 9 apple;  
There are 11 mangoes and 9 apple;  
There are 12 mangoes and 9 apple;  
There are 13 mangoes and 9 apple;  
There are 14 mangoes and 9 apple;  
There are 15 mangoes and 9 apple;  
There are 16 mangoes and 9 apple;  
There are 17 mangoes and 9 apple;  
There are 18 mangoes and 9 apple;
```

How do I achieve this using awk and shell scripting (or even perl) ? The version of awk that we have is /usr/xpg4/bin/awk. I am not familiar with arrays and that's why need some assistance.
Thanks !

PS: Just updated the requirement to append apple "value" to the mangoes "value" .

Comment: It's very hard to understand how the two files come together to form your output. Could you try clarifying a bit more?

Comment: Florin, the o/p file just uses the values generated from the requirements.txt and range.txt files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
    {
        sets = 0+$1
        mbrs = 0+$2
        for (i=1; i<=sets; i++)
            groups[idx++] = mbrs
    }

    END {
        for (idx in groups) {
            getline < range
            printf "There is %d apple;\n", $1
            for (i=2; i<=groups[idx]; i++) {
                getline < range
                printf "There are %d mangoes;\n", $1
            }
        }
    }
' range=range.txt requirements.txt
```

or

```
perl -Mautodie -nE '
    BEGIN { open $range, "<", shift }
    next unless /(\d+)s (\d+)m/;
    ($sets, $mbrs) = ($1, $2);
    for $i (1..$sets) {
        chomp( $n = <$range> );
        say "There is $n apple;";
        for $j (2..$mbrs) {
            chomp( $n = <$range> );
            say "There are $n mangoes;";
        }
    }
' range.txt requirements.txt
```

Comment: +1 for understanding the requirement and answering it.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, this one worked perfectly too. However, i just need the apple "count" to be appended to the "mangoes "count" as shown below. Hope that is not going to be a big deal !

Comment: It should not be a big deal. In fact, I will leave that as an exercise for the reader ;) All you have to do is remember the value when you print the apples line, and add that to the output for each mango. You are expected to do *some* of the work.

Comment: Thanks Glenn ! I will start researching on arrays. That was a good start. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F "[sm]" '{ for (set=1; set<=$1; set++) {
                   getline ct < "range.txt"
                   print "There is " ct " apple;"
                   for (member=1; member<=$2; member++) {
                     getline ct < "range.txt"
                     print "There are " ct " mangoes;"
                   }
                 }
               }' requirements.txt
```

This parses `requirements.txt` using the `s` and `m` characters as delimiters. As it loops over the two numbers, it uses each line in `range.txt` as a `ct` variable to be displayed in the output.

Comment: Greg, that worked perfectly.. However I just realised that we need the o/p in a slightly different format where we get the "apple" count appended to the "mangoes" count as shown above (sorry, I could not indent it better !) I hope that is not going to be a big change to the script.